# Channel Estimate for OFDM shows distortion for first last order samples

Tags: ofdm, distortion, channel

The Channel Gain Estimation was obtained using Least Square method as follows:

Hk= mean(Rx_LTS ./ Tx_LTS, 2);  k= -26 to 26

Where Rx_LTS is the received long training sequence (52 samples after removing the 12 zeros-subcarriers) and Tx_LTS is the known LTS (52 samples).

The plot of this linear channel estimate shows high distortion of low and high-ordered-samples (in the beginning and end).

The real transmission of the OFDM-IEEE 802.11a signal was performed using ADALM-Pluto SDR for different gain of the Tx and Rx SDRs.

The magnitude of my transmitted signal (fed to the Tx-Plut) is 0.5 v peak after normalization (satisfying the ADC maximum input 0dBFS=0.625 v peak). My received signal amplitude is approximately 0.4-0.5 after Rx-Gain amplification.
I tried several transmission but I obtain a very deterioration in Channel Gain magnitude for the first and last samples.

What is the cause for this issue!

Also, how can I calculate the Channel delay spread[image]

[image]
[image]